# Translating salutations like "Mr." to Dutch

Tags: contacts, translation

We are using civi 4.7.16 on Joomla with a Dutch translation; not all terms are translated.

Our problem is that we cannot change the beginning of a message: "Mr." to the dutch version "Beste {contact.first_name}" of some of our contacts.
Civi says: "sorry, we can not do that..." connection refused.

Answer (score 1):

1st problem solved by typing 1957 contacts, pffff...
2nd connection problem solved by disabling geocoding